# Divide cell or array of arbitrary size into pieces of defined size

Tags: arrays, matlab, cells, divide

I have a list of coordinate data that I am trying to divide into pieces small enough to send to a microcontroller.

Currently I have a cell of data that looks like this which is quite large:

```
    [46.06,32.98]
    [15.66,78,42]
```

Etc.

I need to round the values so I convert it to a matrix with cell2mat and use the round function. Then it looks like this where there are two colums:

```
    46 32
    15 78
```

Etc.

MATLAB calls this a (nx2) double in the variable window, n being all the coordinate pairs.

I want to split this double array into sections of five rows of coordinates, because my Arduino can only handle so much data at one time. The amount of coordinate pairs is often not a multiple of 5, so I need to fill the rest with null.

I have the rest from there.

```
    Centroid = {blobSelects.Centroid}.'; %where I create the coordinate cell
    raws = cell2mat(Centroid); %I create the nx2 double
    cleans = round(raws); %I round the values

    %Here I write it to a table
    T = cell2table(cleans,'VariableNames',{'X','Y'}); 

    % and save it on a microSD card.
    dlmwrite('E:\data.txt', 'tabledata.txt', 'delimiter', '\t')
```

Comment: And what data type do you want the result to be? A cell array of 5x2 matrices?

Comment: Indeed, that would be very much desired. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
A = randi([0, 100],randi(50),2); %// replace with your actual matrix
padSize = ceil(size(A,1)/5)*5 - size(A,1);
A = vertcat(A,nan(padSize,2));

out1 = mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)/5)*5,2); %// Desired cell array
```

If you want it as a 3D matrix (as they all are of same size 5x2), you could use

```
out = permute(reshape(A,5,size(A,1)/5,[]),[1 3 2]);
```